# Laravel can not pass variable from controller to component

Tags: laravel, laravel-components

I can not see my variable in component

Controller

```
class DigitalContentController extends Controller
{
    public function productsList(){
        $contents = DigitalContent::all();
        return view('pages.digitalContents', compact(['contents']));
    }
}
```

digitalContents

```
@extends('layouts.base')

@section('body')

<x-content-card></x-content-card>

@endsection
```

Component

```
@foreach ( $contents ?? [] as $item )
    {{ $item->name }}
@endforeach
```

Even when I echo variable before `return view` I can see the variable.

```
class DigitalContentController extends Controller
{
    public function productsList(){
        $contents = DigitalContent::all();
        echo $contents
        return view('pages.digitalContents', compact(['contents']));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you've to parse the variable to the component. So it should be:

```
<x-content-card :contents="$contents"></x-content-card>
```

Don't forget to add contents  to your component class